# Is a dynamically allocated 2D array automatically deleted after the program exits?

Tags: c++11

I am learning about destructors right now because I am making this assignment about matrices (we're supposed to make a Matrix class and overload operators to do Matrix operations and me and the person I am going to mention in the next bit were planning to also make it perform Gauss-Jordan elimination, if this is relevant) which are represented in this assignment through dynamic 2D arrays.

I heard someone talk about using a destructor for the deletion process of the arrays. I started reading about destructors and one of the events that calls a destructors that seemed like the only time a destructor would be used in an application like this was the termination of the program, so I am left kind of confused as to why he'd need a destructor? What's the significance of a destructor in an application like this?

Comment: Each `new` should be matched by a `delete`, and each `new[]` with a `delete[]`. If you don't, then you'll have a leak. That's one reason *not* to use pointers and dynamic allocation yourself, and instead use something like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: A destructor is called every time an object goes out of scope. Consider this `}` as calls to destructors.

Comment: It is hard to tell what does have significance in an application like this.  It's a school assignment to exercise (usually) a specific skill. We don't know what skill you are to exercise. If it's building well built classes, then you are supposed to write destructors because you will get reduced points for not doing so. Classes like Matrix are usually put in libraries. The author doesn't know what kind of application his or her class will be used in. Most applications cannot live without destructors. *Your assignment* might be able to get away with skipping them, but this doesn't mean much.

Comment: I think its pretty clear I meant significance with respect to the task not significance in a real world/practical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is:

## Yes. And No.

#### No:

If the process creates an object with `new` and terminates without calling `delete` on that same object, the object is never destructed. **Any action that would be done by the destructor is simply not done**.

This action can be stuff that is required for consistency of external data. Like pushing something to a database. Or like flushing a cache to disk. What action is missed depends entirely on the destructor.

#### Yes:

The memory that was occupied by the process is not lost to the system. Your process requested some chunks of memory from the system's kernel, so that it was able to construct its objects within that memory. The kernel keeps track of which memory pages it has allocated to which process, and *it does not care a bit what that process does with it*. The kernel is entirely oblivious to which objects were constructed within the memory.

When a process exits, the kernel will simply reclaim any memory that's still allocated to the process. As such, you don't permanently loose memory by forgetting to `delete` objects at shutdown.

However, this reclaiming affects memory use, only. The contents of any cache that wasn't flushed remains unflushed. And the external files that were in an inconsistent state when the process terminated will remain in that inconsistent state forever.

---

So, bottom line: Memory will be reclaimed by the kernel anyway. But it's generally not a good idea to forget cleanup. It's better not to get into the habit of being lazy, because that habit will bite you severely down the road.